# Switch to alternate ViewController programmatically on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am reasonably new to IOS below is a screenshot of my app structure -

[image]

There are various tableViewcontroller / uiviewcontrollers which connect to a tab bar controller - all pretty standard I guess.

The colourful shot is the homepage - I would like users to be able to click on one of the 4 tabs and navigate to one of the other pages - though i'm struggling on how to to this programatically.

I have attached all the buttons as ib-actions and have given all the screesn storyboard id's.

The following is my code so far -

```
- (IBAction)btnCult:(id)sender {

    UIViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"culture"];


    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

This does nothing - where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try add this it IBAction:

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

It should takes you to first tab, by changing index you change the tabs(views)